# Why is a control's load method being called when a hidden form is shown?

Tags: .net, winforms, dll, user-controls, load

I have a form that contains a user control which is contained in a separate DLL. The DLL is included as a project reference. When I show the form for the first time, I would expect the control's load method to be called. However, if I hide the containing form and later show the form I would NOT expect the control's load() method to be called again, but it is. The form's load method is not being called again when the hidden form is showed.

Can someone please explain why the control's load method is being called again when the control is already loaded? This is causing a problem because the control's load method adds event handler's (not my design) to handle events that already have handlers defined.

Comment: Is this a windows app or a web app?

Comment: The MSDN article for UserControl.Load is filled with warnings about this.  Use a variable of type bool in your class that you set to true after setting the event handlers.  So that you don't do it twice.  And also really consider using the constructor instead.

Comment: This is a windows app. I'll check the UserControl.Load documentation. The issue is easy to fix. I just wanted to know why it happened. This is for an onscreen keyboard. There is no need to add the events at run time. I suspect the original Developer just did not want to manually add them using the Designer.

Comment: Oh look, the top of the documentation says "Note...for an MDIChild form the Load event will occur each time the child form is shown." 'Funny that a Google search on when the load event is called for user control did not turn up anything useful. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Before you respond, I guess technically that there is no "design time" with .Net so there is really no harm to adding the handlers at "run-time" so long as they are added in the constructor and not the load event handler.